# Why GDB backtrace show to me only parent's call instead of nested functions?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, backtrace

I'm trying backtrace on gdb, basically with this on setupCommands (in VSCode):

```
{
    "description": "Backtrace",
    "text": "set backtrace past-main",
    "ignoreFailures": true
}
```

When I do bt -10, it show to me only the parent's call, not the nested one.

For example, if I have: functA call funcB (and inside funcB i call funcC and funcD), if I stop at the end of funcB, I can just see funcA and funcB (without C and D).

How can I enable whole tracing in the backtrace? To see EVERY instructions calls at any level, on every thread? (I just need last 1000, for example).

Comment: The GDB output you are referring to would be far more useful as an explanation of what you are seeing than the VSCode config, which is largely irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to have misunderstood what the *backtrace* is. It is the *call-stack backtrace*, not a trace of the execution path of the code.

If you stop in B, then C and D are not in the call stack.  If you were to stop in C you would see `A->B->C` and if you stop in D then `A->B->D`.

From the [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Backtrace.html) (my emphasis):

> *A backtrace is a summary of how your program got where it is. It shows one line per frame, for many frames, starting with the currently executing frame (frame zero), followed by its caller (frame one), **and on up the stack**.*

here "frame" refers to a *stack-frame*.

Comment: well, but if C and D are executed on B, at the end of B function I should see C and D on the backtrace. But I don't see them... What I need is the stack of all (last 1000) instructions executed till the breakpoint reach. Is there any way on doing this?

Comment: Repeating your question in a comment will not elicit a different answer. The simple point is that _backtrace_ does not do what you think it does.  You have asked an X-Y question.  If this answer is not what you need, then you asked the wrong question.  If you want instruction or call sequence trace (not the same thing BTW) then ask about that.  The question you asked was about why the GDB backtrace behaves as it does, and that is answered.  But still you don't have what you need to know.  Ask a (new) question about what you actually want and how to achieve it.